# geoPlugin returns false in PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

I am using geoPlugin - http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php

```
echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
```

I am using this code but it returns "false".
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your code step by step.

First echo or dump the return of the API.

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

Here you can check it there is a return value. Now check if you get an serialized string.

If your return value is empty. Go to your `php.ini` and set the `allow_url_fopen` value to `On`. Otherwise you can't fetch the content from other sites with `file_get_contents`.